# Strange alignment issues with Rails and Materialize CSS icons

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, materialize, slim-lang

I am having a very strange issue using Materialize CSS's icons in a table. They do not seem to align properly.

Screenshot: (All personal details blurred out.)

[image: Screenshot of a HTML table with some columns on the right misaligned.]

Here is my Slim template:

```
.container
  h1
    | View Users
  = form_for :user, url: "/users" do |f|
    table
        tr
          th width="30px" ID
          th width="80px" User ID
          th Email Address
          th First Name
          th Last Name
          th Type
          th Notes
          th width="20px" class="material-icons" delete
          th width="20px" class="material-icons" mode-edit
        - @users.each do |i|
          tr
            td = i.id
            td = i.uid
            td = i.email
            td = i.first_name
            td = i.last_name
            td = i.user_type
            td = i.notes
            td = link_to 'delete', user_path(i), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "material-icons", :style => 'color: black'
            td = link_to 'mode-edit', [:edit, i], :class => "material-icons", :style => 'color: black'
            br
        tr
            td
              input type="text" value="ID" readonly="readonly"
            td
              == f.text_field :uid, :id => "uid", :placeholder => "User ID"
            td
              == f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email Address"
            td
              == f.text_field :first_name, :id => "fname", :placeholder => "First Name"
            td
              == f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name"
            td
              == f.text_field :user_type, :placeholder => "Type"
            td
              == f.text_field :notes, :placeholder => "Notes"
    .row
      .actions
        .col.s2
          a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
            == f.submit "Add"
        .col.s7
          span
        .col.s3 align="right"
          a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="/users/new" Open Form
```

Here is my `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me resolve this very strange issue.

Comment: It looks like the row with inputs has fewer `td`s than previous rows. Can you try to add two empty `td`s there?

Comment: @MuradYusufov I've experimented with it a bit but the problem is still there. Trying it now.

Comment: @MuradYusufov Did absolutely nothing

Comment: @MuradYusufov Changed the icon to "create" and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the icon I used (edit-mode) was causing problems with the table. I tested it separately and it still caused those problems by itself.

The way I fixed the issue was by changing the icon from "edit-mode" to "create". That immediately fixed the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14230678)

Comment: @Serjik I am the author

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14230678)

Comment: @VDWWD I fixed it